# how to debug cookie rejection by the browser

Tags: debugging, cookies, browser, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Using either Chrome (Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)) or Firefox (developer edition 56.0b3 (64-bit)), I am unable to understand why I do not see the cookie sent in the response header, get stored in the browser local storage.

My HTTP request header is as follows:

```
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:3000/SignIn
content-type: application/json
origin: http://localhost:3000
Content-Length: 46
Connection: keep-alive
```

My response header is as follows:

```
x-powered-by: Express
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
access-control-allow-origin: *
Vary: *
content-length: 32
etag: W/"20-LcTp1bBlcTS0d04Fav3DxiGJgW0"
set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3ABBRbPNpMXcweAtfATcULtOOzgMwlBrtC.qX8a9M%2BrsKsjhdeRL7eAyzFrkjQMOoWw36DIhSdhiGQ; Domain=http://localhost:3000; Path=/; HttpOnly
date: Sat, 19 Aug 2017 08:15:01 GMT
connection: close
```

---

I do not see any cookie being stored, using the 'Storage' tab of Firefox dev tools or the 'Application' tab of Chrome. Neither can I find any error message in these tools that tell me why the cookie was not stored.

What am I missing?

Comment: Version of your Firefox? (_Firefox had some bug about showing cookie, of course now it fixed_)

Comment: I've updated the description to mention versions of both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Thanks, Non-stable versions of FF is stable enough, but can you please check the code with stable version of FF? or provide a testcase?

Answer (score 0):

I am on Firefox Developer Edition 93 and the console (*ctrl* + *shift* + *k*) shows exactly this information — this scenario is for setting a third-party cookie in `sameSite == lax` scenario and thus a cookie is being `rejected for invalid domain`.

[image: cookie rejection displayed by firefox]